# A RECURSIVE method accepts two parameters: a String s and an int n

Tags: java, recursion

(I actually don't know how to write this code, I checked internet find it maybe look like this, but when I run it, it didnt work.

For example, input ("College",2). It should output ("College","College"). But it shows cannot read. 
I just don't know how to solve this problem.
Please teach me how to write this code.

-------Write a RECURSIVE method called printStr that accepts two parameters: a String s and an int n.  This method should return a String containing the String s written n times, separated by a space each time.  Assume n >= 1.

For example, calling printStr("Lehman", 2) should return "Lehman Lehman", and calling printStr("The Bronx", 4) should return "The Bronx The Bronx The Bronx The Bronx".

Call your class Homework5_2.  In the main method, call your method printStr several times to test it.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework5_2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    String s = args[1];

    System.out.print(printStr(s,n));

}

public static String printStr(String s, int n){
    if (n==0) {
        return "";
    }
    return s + printStr(s, n - 1);
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem that you are dealing with?

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code. Quoting assignment as you posted it:

> "separated by a space"
>   "Assume n >= 1"
>   "In the main method, call your method printStr several times to test it."

So, write explicit calls in `main()`, don't use `args`. Add the missing space, and don't call or check for `0`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println('"' + printStr("College", 2) + '"');
    System.out.println('"' + printStr("Lehman", 2) + '"');
    System.out.println('"' + printStr("The Bronx", 4) + '"');
}
public static String printStr(String s, int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return s;
    return s + ' ' + printStr(s, n - 1);
}
```

Added quote (`'"'`) to `println()` to ensure no extra spaces were added.

*Output*

```
"College College"
"Lehman Lehman"
"The Bronx The Bronx The Bronx The Bronx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, take your homework. But it will be better if you will try harder to do something by yourself.

```
static int maxn;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scanner.next();
    maxn = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print(printStr(s, 0));
}
public static String printStr(String s, int n){
    if(n == maxn){
        return "";
    } else if (n != 0){
        s = " " + s;
    }
    return s + printStr(s, n + 1);
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this n value?

Comment: when I run it, it shows*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Homework5_2.main(Homework5_2.java:9)

Comment: `String s = args[0];` try this
Do you pass any parameters from console? Or you just run your program in IDE?

Comment: Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Homework5_2.main(Homework5_2.java:9)

Comment: Yes. What I copied is everything there. I think just in IDE.

Comment: Do you really want understand something? Or just copy paste?
You are trying to read some argument value from `agrs`, so read in google how `args` works and what is that in general. Also you have declared Scanner, but you don't use it. Now I'll give you working main(), but it will be better for you, if you try to figure out how things work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want to know how it works. I just tried so many times I can't find where is wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: But, this question asks me like input("College",2) output should be("College College").  It depends what we input, then output are different. the code now only print myString

Comment: Sorry. I change to Scanner now. However: the output is:college 2
 college  college   college    college     college      college       college        college         college          college.    It should be only two college print out.

Comment: Use the scanner to get input String s = scanner.nextLine();

Comment: No. I can input, but there is no output.

Comment: so instead of  String s = "myString"; put String s = keyboard.nextLine(); and in the console enter something in.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework5_2 {


 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n= keyboard.nextInt();
     String s = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.print(printStr(s,n));
  }
 public static String printStr(String s, int n){
     if(n == 0){
        return "";
    
     }
     return s + printStr(s, n + 1);
 }

Comment: WOW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It works now!  This is so hard!!!! Thank you so much.@Sloth and @Hardik Patel

Comment: @Sloth it should be nextLine haha or the example "The Bronx" wont work

Comment: @LiXiaolong and you don't understand why? haha =)
alright, bye man

Comment: @Sloth I start JAVA 3 weeks. I don't really understand why yet. But thank you so much.Enjoy your rest of night.

Comment: haha I think we have all been there. "The Bronx" will work with  String s = keyboard.nextLine();

Comment: FYI: The entire discussion about `args` is maybe good for OP learning about them, but is off-assignment: *"In the main method, call your method printStr several times to test it."*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats wrong with your code... just didnt put a space..

```
    public static String printStr(String s, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return s;
    }
    return s + " " + printStr(s, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: This is helpful too, but it still don't work. Thank you!

Comment: change it from String s = args[1]; to String s = args[0]; and if you are running in eclipse, right click the .java  file. Run As - Run Configurations, go to the argument tab and enter a word inside the "Program arguments" section

Comment: I am not familiar with Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Add space and give newline at the last of string.

```
public static String printStr(String s, int n){
    if (n==0) {
        return "\n";
    }
    return s+" " + printStr(s, n - 1);
}
```